Email capture plug-in - Suitescript - search folder returns null
I am writing a script to save attachments to the file cabinet in a specific folder.  If the folder where the file needs to go does not exist, it gets created and that works great. But, if the folder already exist I have to locate the folder id.  The script below is what I am using to search for the folder. If I run the code in the script debugger, the folder id is returned.  But when it runs from the plug-in receiving an email, the folder id is null.
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Folder: ' + folderName + ' ' + e.getCode());


var filterExpression = [ [ 'parent', 'anyOf', '20681' ],
             and',
                 [ 'name', 'is', folderName ] ];
// Define search columns
var columns = new Array();
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn( 'internalid' ));
var folderSearch = nlapiSearchRecord('folder', null, filterExpression, columns);
            
var folderId = folderSearch[0].getValue('internalid');
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Folder: ' + folderId);

I am thinking it is a permissions issue with the user running the plug-in.  I changed the "Execute As Role" of the plug-in to a role that I believe has the necessary permissions, but the folder id continues to be null.

So it works when executing as administator?
